# Security implications when using NGINX to proxy cookie authentication

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have two web apps: authme.com and dummy.com. The login form on dummy.com needs to call authme.com for authentication. Since cookies must be on the same domain for authentication to work, I plan to use an NGINX proxy. The NGINX configuration is as follows:

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:80;
    server_name dummy.com www.dummy.com, *.dummy.com;
    root /;

    location /login/ {
        proxy_pass https://authme.com/login;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Are there any security considerations I should be aware of? What are the potential downsides, and are there alternative approaches? Thanks!